# ISO образ на C#

Tags: c#, iso-образ

Озаботился вопросом о программном способе создания ISO образов из проекта на C#. Каким образом лучше реализовать подобный трюк? Есть библиотека DiskUtils, но она сторонняя ,кто-то когда-то пользовался ей или есть еще какие-то способы?
UPD.
Попытался использовать библиотеку .NET DiscUtils (http://discutils.codeplex.com/) и столкнулся с проблемой построения собственно iso-образа. Согласно документации к библиотеке, построение файла-образа производится так:

> How to create a new ISO:
>
> *CDBuilder builder = new CDBuilder();*
> *builder.UseJoliet = true;*
> *builder.VolumeIdentifier = "A_SAMPLE_DISK";*
> *builder.AddFile(@"Folder\Hello.txt", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World!"));*
> *builder.Build(@"C:\temp\sample.iso");*
>
> You can add files as byte arrays
> (shown above), as files from the
> Windows filesystem, or as a Stream. By
> using a different form of Build, you
> can get a Stream to the ISO file,
> rather than writing it to the Windows
> filesystem.

Мой код:

```
//обработка сообщения о подключении флешки
private void onDriveArrived(object sender, DriveDetectorEventArgs e)
{
    DriveInfo dri = new DriveInfo(e.Drive);
    if ((dri.DriveType & DriveType.Removable) != DriveType.Removable)
        return;

    

try
        {
    //создаю объект под будущий iso
            CDBuilder builder = new CDBuilder();
    //определяю рут-директорию флешки
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(e.Drive);

    //подключаю флаг Joliet-он в стандарте ISO9660 позволяет поддерживать
    //имена файлов более 8 символов
            builder.UseJoliet = true;
    //прописываю метку диска - смонтированного в виртуальное устройство iso-образа
            builder.VolumeIdentifier = "TEST";

    //получаю имена с путями всех файлов на флешке
            List<string> names = GetFilesPathToISO(e.Drive);
            foreach (string name in names)
    //каждый файл из списка добавляю в будущий iso
                builder.AddFile(name, name);

    //создается iso-файл
            builder.Build(@"d:\test.iso");

        }
        catch (Exception err) 
            {MessageBox.Show(err.Message + "\n" + err.StackTrace);}

    }  
}
```

Запускаю, вставляю флешку с данными, начинает создаваться образ, доходит до определенного момента выкидывает исключение типа "недостаточно места на диске" (хотя места на диске предостаточно) и прерывает работу. В созданном файле-образе при открытии его архиватором находятся какие-то бессодержательные файлы. И что делать - не знаю, да и спросить собственно не у кого...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: А чем отличается создание ISO на C# от любого другого языка? «Берёшь образ, делаешь образ!» (ц)

Либо вам нужна сторонняя библиотека, которая это умеет, либо нужно знать формат ISO и создавать файл вручную. Встроенных в C# (как впрочем и в любой другой язык) средств нету.

Comment: требуется реализовать функционал создания ISO образа флэшки средствами C# и, т.к. я ранее не сталкивался с подобным вопросом, прошу совета у сообщества

Comment: Ну вам по-сути уже дал ответ VladD, ищите библиотеку у которой есть биндинг к C# и которая умеет это делать либо пишите код сами. В чем проблема-то? Не знаете что выбрать, или не можете спецификацию на ISO нагуглить?

Comment: проблем несколько:
1. нашел библиотеку .Net DiscUtils, но не получается корректно создать файл
2. очевидно в предыдущем своем комментарии я обратил внимание на то, что сталкиваюсь с подобной проблемой впервые, поэтому проблема не нагуглить, а что именно нагуглить, т.к. те проблемы, с которыми я столкнулся при использовании вышеуказанной библиотеки, не описаны (по крайней мере я описания не нашел)
3. и да, если кто-то уже сталкивался с подобным вопросом, то хотелось бы узнать что использовалось для решения проблемы

Comment: @alexelev, Если Вы столкнулись с конкретными проблемами связанными с выбранной Вами библиотекой, то и опишите их в вопросе.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то iso образ - это обычный zip архив с изменённым расширением. Так что же вам мешает создать тот же самый zip?

P.S. то что у вас не хватает очков уважения для постинга скриншотов - не беда!
Лично у меня всегда для таких целей есть сайты вроде `radikal.cc` и `fastpic.ru`

Comment: @SuperCreeper, так да нет так. ISO - не обычный zip-архив, хотя и нечто достаточно похожее на него. К тому же форматов ISO несколько (mode 1 и mode 2)

Comment: @gecube но ISO может быть обычным zip-архивом. Тем более, что такие "образы" смогут открыть почти любые программы для нарезки дисков.

Comment: А зачем нужна переменная `dir`?

Comment: Да, вы правы, она тут лишняя. Я пробовал несколько вариантов получения добавления файлов в builder и она осталась от предыдущих попыток.

Comment: Для начала, не могли бы вы показать код собственно вашего метода `GetFilesPathToISO`?

Comment: @Helisia iso-образ - это посекторная копия диска. Он *никак* не может быть zip-архивом!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Попробуйте использовать вместо флешки с данными какую-нибудь папку на жёстком диске.
2. Я особо не шарю в C#, но я думаю, что вам всё-таки стоит попробовать способ с zip-архивом. [Подробнее здесь.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498572/how-to-compress-a-directory-into-a-zip-file-programmatically)

Comment: склоняюсь к этой идее, т.к. с iso-файлами мало что выходит :)

Answer (score 0):

Не смотня на то, что ISO открывается архиваторами, он не является зип-архивом.
Во-первых Исошка это посекторная копия диска. Во-вторых там могут быть данные загрузочного сектора(то есть Partition созданный как Active). **В зипе же такой информации нету вообще и не может быть в принципе.**

Я не знаю даной ситуации автора вопроса... Вполне возможно что костыль с зип-архивом в его случае прокатит. 
Но вообще эт неправильный путь.

А проавильных путей только 2:

1. Искать библиотеку с реализованным созданием виртуальных образов логических дисков
2. написать свою (глупый путь, если чесно.)

> "недостаточно места на диске" (хотя места на диске предостаточно)

^ Это может относится к:

- логическому диску винчестера где ты размещаешь исошку
- логическому диску винчестера где ты размещаешь временные файлы (например диск С)
- самой исошке (например какие-то лимиты на создание исо-файла. То есть пытаешся всунуть 701 мегабайт когда некий лимит говорит что должно быть 700) (просто догадка, не в курсе какая там лимитация может быть)

И еще черт-знает какие варианты. В даном случае это слишком общая ошибка которая лично мне ничего не говорит. Да и с таким обилием вариантов сложно верить тебе, что там и вправду есть место на диске.

Нужно смотреть на каком именно шагу она выскакивает и на все данные которые ты размещаешь. И на настройки создания ISOшки....

В общем... если тебе **НЕ** важно следование спецификации полноценного ISO - создай зип и не мучайся. В теории это может и прокатить для твоих нужд.

Если же тебе важно получить настоящую ISOшку которая отвечает всем спецификациям - или разбирайся детальнее спрашивая на форуме посвященном даной библиотеке(или на ветке проблем гитхаба, если такая есть) или же ищи другую библиотеку.

Изобретать же свой велосипед не советую.