# Как создать zip-архив блоками заданного размера?

Tags: c#, zip

Это продолжение [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274166/iso-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c), где я пытаюсь для создания zip-файлов использовать open source библиотеку [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/). Возник вопрос организации архивов в виде томов определенного размера (например, для записи архивов >4Гб на FAT32 диск). Может кто-то из тех, кто использовал данную библиотеку, подсказать вариант выполнения?
З.Ы. Документация по либе крайне скудная и плохо организована, поэтому сам найти способ не смог :(

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то для zip разбиение на тома происходит через простое разбиение файла на блоки байтов заданного размера, без каких либо дополнительных заголовков.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [dotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) - он позволяет решить вашу задачу.

DotNetZip example:

```c-shrp
int SegmentsCreated ;
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
  zip.UseUnicode= true;  // utf-8
  zip.AddDirectory(@"MyDocuments\ProjectX");
  zip.Comment = "This zip was created at " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("G") ;
  zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 100*1024 ; // 100k segments
  zip.Save("MyFiles.zip");

  SegmentsCreated = zip.NumberOfSegmentsForMostRecentSave ;
}
```

Comment: Вот здесь вроде бы форк с продолжением разработки: https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd

Comment: И в новой версии зафиксили наконец [это](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/14087): [(1)](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/pull/24), [(2)](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/issues/48).

Answer (score 0):

Можете простым кодом вроде этого поделить уже готовый zip-файл на части:

```
public static void SplitFile(string source, long partSize, string destinationFormat, int firstFileNumber = 0)
{
    var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(source);

    var buffer = new byte[80*1024];
    var position = sourceStream.Position;
    var fileNumber = firstFileNumber;

    while (position < sourceStream.Length)
    {
        var filename = String.Format(destinationFormat, fileNumber);

        using(var destinationStream = File.Create(filename))
        {
            var count = 0;

            do
            {
                count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.Min(buffer.LongLength, partSize - destinationStream.Position));
                destinationStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                position += count;
            } while (count > 0);
        }

        fileNumber++;
    }
}
```

вызов:

```
SplitFile(
    source: @"C:\test\test.zip", 
    destinationFormat: @"C:\test\test.z{0:D2}", 
    partSize: 100000*1024
    );
```

Если хотите сразу писать в несколько файлов, то конструктору ZipFile можно подавать в качестве аргумента экземпляры Stream/Filestream.

При желании, можно сделать наследника для одного из этих классов, который и будет автоматически писать в несколько файлов. Это не сложно, просто кода нужно относительно много, т.к. требуется что бы поток был Seekable и Readable(не смотря на то, что мы собираемся только писать в поток)